# Artifactory ignores version of a library from remote (maven central)?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I have following Artifactory (6.12.1) settings

Remote repositories:

- central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
- jboss: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
- jcenter https://jcenter.bintray.com
- jvnet-nexus-staging: http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/staging/
- rabbit-milestone: https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/maven-milestones
- repository.spring.milestone: https://repo.spring.io/milestone
- repository.spring.snapshot: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
- sonatype-oss-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Virtual repositories

- libs-release: libs-release-local, central, repository.spring.milestone, jcenter, jboss, rabbit-milestone
- libs-snapshot: libs-snapshot-local, repository.spring.snapshot, jvnet-nexus-staging, sonatype-oss-snapshots

I'm trying to build spring-boot locally and I've forced all remote repositories from my system to go through our Artifactory. So I've added to my `.m2/settings.xml` following section:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>artifactory</id>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>spring-milestone</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>spring-snapshot</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>rabbit-milestone</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>spring-milestone</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>spring-snapshot</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

I've verified that everything works and our projects install dependencies correctly. This should be all ok.

Now the spring-boot project [has repository definitions in root pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/58734873ddff6dfba8554682b02f02ae0ab4a489/pom.xml#L153), but my settings override it, which means maven is trying to download from our Artifactory (as intended).

But it get's stuck on this dependency

```
[INFO] -------------< org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs >--------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot Docs 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT                   [80/88]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.pom (737 B at 12 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
Downloading from snapshots: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
Downloading from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.pom (2.6 kB at 20 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec/1.0-alpha-2/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec-1.0-alpha-2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec/1.0-alpha-2/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec-1.0-alpha-2.pom (4.3 kB at 73 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Spring Boot Build 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spring Boot Docs ................................... FAILURE [  0.486 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-31T17:55:28+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-boot-docs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.15.9 -> org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:specs:pom:1.1 in central (https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
```

When I look at maven central, the version is there

[image: maven central]

When I look at `central` in Artifactory the `org.apache.geronimo.specs:specs` artifact is also there

[image: central repo]

But it's never downloaded and cached, there is only `1.4`

[image: centra-cache repo]

I've tried purging the whole `org.apache.geronimo` tree from Artifactory caches and from my local maven cache, but it still only sees the `1.4` version.

Is there some other cache that I should try to refresh? Or is it an Artifactory bug? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it is connected to the error, but usually, if you have a company Artifactory, you put a `<mirror>` entry into your `settings.xml` so that you can be sure all requests are redirected to that mirror.

Comment: I've tried using `<mirror>` but had some problems with it - overriding repositories worked the first time I've tried it.

Comment: Try to debug it by using the trace query parameter, for example curl https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec/1.0-alpha-2/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec-1.0-alpha-2.pom?trace

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky that is a neat trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @DrorBereznitsky, I was able to figure out the cause of the problem

Using the helpful `?trace` as

```
curl -v -u 'user:password' 'https://artifactory.secret.com/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom?trace'
```

I was able to obtain the following logs

```
Request ID: 9f425b1c
Repo Path ID: libs-release:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
Method Name: GET
Time: 2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z
Steps: 
2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z Received request
2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z Retrieving info from virtual repository 'libs-release' type Maven
2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
2019-09-05T15:41:07.877Z Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Unable to find resource in libs-release:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Intercepting cached virtual resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Intercepting cached virtual resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Searching for info in aggregated repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending the nested virtual repository 'libs-release'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective local repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective local cache repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective remote repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective remote repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective remote repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective remote repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Appending collective remote repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Processing request as a release resource
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Searching for the resource within libs-release-local
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Unable to find resource in libs-release-local:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.879Z Searching for the resource within central-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.880Z Unable to find resource in central-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.880Z Searching for the resource within repository.spring.milestone-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.881Z Unable to find resource in repository.spring.milestone-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.881Z Searching for the resource within jcenter-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.881Z Unable to find resource in jcenter-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.881Z Searching for the resource within jboss-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.882Z Unable to find resource in jboss-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.882Z Searching for the resource within rabbit-milestone-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.882Z Unable to find resource in rabbit-milestone-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.882Z Searching for the resource within central
2019-09-05T15:41:07.883Z Unable to find resource in central-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.883Z Executing any AltRemotePath user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.883Z Appending matrix params to remote request URL
2019-09-05T15:41:07.883Z Using remote request URL - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.883Z Executing HEAD request to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.906Z Found remote resource with last modified time - Wed Jun 28 09:19:33 UTC 2006
2019-09-05T15:41:07.906Z Found remote resource with ETag - "9bef270e593bf6dcc37a4e3014b5f94a"
2019-09-05T15:41:07.906Z Found remote resource with content length - 13452
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Found remote resource with checksums - [ChecksumInfo{type=SHA-1, original='5274e75bb357203fbc61c529b7bfc174357dbff8', actual='null'}, ChecksumInfo{type=MD5, original='9bef270e593bf6dcc37a4e3014b5f94a', actual='null'}]
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Returning found remote resource info
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Resource was found in central
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Resource is an exact match - returning
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Returning resource as found in the aggregated repositories
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Intercepting found resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Intercepting found resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Creating a resource handle from 'central'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Target repository is configured to retain artifacts locally - resource will be stored and the streamed to the user
2019-09-05T15:41:07.913Z Remote repository is online
2019-09-05T15:41:07.914Z Unable to find resource in central-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.914Z Found expired cached resource but remote is newer = false. Cached resource: 0, Remote resource: 1151486373000
2019-09-05T15:41:07.914Z Force expiration on the cached resource = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.914Z Resource isn't cached and isn't expired = true
2019-09-05T15:41:07.914Z Asserting valid deployment path
2019-09-05T15:41:07.915Z Creating a resource handle from 'central-cache:org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.915Z Unable to find the resource - throwing exception
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Unable to find cached resource stream handle, continuing with actual remote download.
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Found no cached resource - starting download
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Downloading and saving
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Eager source JAR fetching enabled = true
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Eager JAR fetching enabled = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Valid Maven artifact info = true
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Artifact has classifier = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Eager JAR and source JAR fetching is not attempted
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Remote property synchronization enabled = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Received remote checksums headers - [ChecksumInfo{type=SHA-1, original='5274e75bb357203fbc61c529b7bfc174357dbff8', actual='null'}, ChecksumInfo{type=MD5, original='9bef270e593bf6dcc37a4e3014b5f94a', actual='null'}]
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Executing any AltRemoteContent user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Received no alternative content handle from a user plugin
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Received no alternative content, received remote checksums headers and searching for existing resources on download is enabled
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Searching for existing resource with SHA-1 '5274e75bb357203fbc61c529b7bfc174357dbff8'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Received no alternative content or existing resource - downloading resource
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Appending matrix params to remote request URL
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Using remote request URL - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Executing any BeforeRemoteDownload user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.916Z Executing GET request to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom
2019-09-05T15:41:07.919Z Downloading content
2019-09-05T15:41:07.919Z Saving resource to central-cache
2019-09-05T15:41:07.975Z Failed to download: Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .
2019-09-05T15:41:07.975Z Executing any AfterRemoteDownload user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.975Z Executed all AfterRemoteDownload user plugins
2019-09-05T15:41:07.975Z Error occurred while downloading artifact: Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Requested resource is found = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Request is HEAD = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Request is for a checksum = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Requested resource was not modified = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Responding with unfound resource
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Setting default response status to '404' reason to 'Resource not found'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Response is an instance of UnfoundRepoResourceReason
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Configured to hide un-authorized resources = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Original response status is auth related = false
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Using original response status of '404' and message 'Failed to transform pom file: Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Sending error with status 404 and message 'Failed to transform pom file: Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .'
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Executing any AfterDownloadErrorAction user plugins that may exist
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Response code wasn't modified by the user plugins
2019-09-05T15:41:07.976Z Sending response with the status '404' and the message 'Failed to transform pom file: Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .'
```

with the interesting part being

```
Error occurred while downloading artifact:
Failed to read POM for 'org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom':
expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</developers>\n    `\n    <p... @91:7) .
```

=> They've simply published an invalid POM and that's why Artifactory is unable to download the dependency

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to simply download this file org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom and edit it to remove the '`' char, then just upload it manually to my artifactory local repository